# Touching a button does not trigger a segue

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uistoryboardsegue

Touching a button does not trigger a segue. I need to hold the button for several seconds to run the push to another screen.

I use Storyboards and IOS 5.

In IOS6 works.

Any suggestions for research?

Thanks

EDIT:

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UITapGestureRecognizer *touchDismissKeyboard = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:touchDismissKeyboard];

    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];



}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)dismissKeyboard
{


}
```

The following code lines are causing the problem:

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer *touchDismissKeyboard = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:touchDismissKeyboard];
```

In IOS 6 works but in IOS5 touch the button for a long time (4-5 seconds) is necessary to trigger segue

Comment: you need to post code which gets called when you press a button.

Comment: UILongPressGestureRecognizer

Comment: What type of button are you using? Are you using gesture recognizers? Please post some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code lines are causing the problem:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *touchDismissKeyboard = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];

[self.view addGestureRecognizer:touchDismissKeyboard];
```